# Can the DbProviderFactory.CreateCommandBuilder actually return a null?

Tags: c#, resharper, sqlconnection, sanitization

I use the following pattern to sanitize database names:

```
var dbProviderFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connection);
using (var commandBuilder = dbProviderFactory.CreateCommandBuilder())
{
    var fooSafe = commandBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(foo)
}
```

but each time I do this R# complains about the `commandBuilder` and says

> Possible System.NullReference exception.

To get rid of this warning I usually put

```
Debug.Assert(commandBuilder != null);
```

after creating the command builder.

I use mostly a `SqlConnection` or `SQLiteConnection`.

There is not much about it in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.createcommandbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) that just says:

> Returns a new instance of the provider's class that implements the DbCommandBuilder class.

I'm never sure whether I should check the command builder for null or just ignore the warning?

Comment: As a side-note, you could have an extension method like [here](https://github.com/matkoch/TestFx/blob/master/src/TestFx.Core/Utilities/Object.NotNull.cs#L26), which would save you an additional assertion line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the documentation says it will return a "new instance" i wouldn't worry about null check.

Resharper is complaining possibly because it is a virtual method and any custom implementation may return null.